# How to deal with view specific Javascript in an MVC website

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I know this question has been asked several times, yet I cannot seem to find a proper solution to my problem.

I'm using CodeIgniter, a PHP framework that follows the MVC (Model-View-Controller) principle.

I have many javascript files like jQuery and other generic libraries that I need for every page that are included in the **head** tag. I also have view specific javascript that are embedded directly in the view in a script block.

An example of the view **customerInfo.php**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // some javascript here for customerInfo view
    // I MUST be able to use PHP variables in this script block ex:
    var customerName = "<?php echo $customerName; ?>";
</script>

<p class="someClass">Hello <?=$customerName?>, may the lord provide you with bananas</p>
```

My Website layout is as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://coolStorybro.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://coolStorybro.com/commonStuff.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">some header stuff</div>

<div class="pageContent">
   <?php echo $view; ?>   // In this case, $view will hold the view customerInfo
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My goal is to have all my javascript at the same place so I can minify it and eventually place it at the bottom of my page for loading optimization.

I am aware that I can store the view specific javascript in a seperate file called **customerInfo.js** and load it in the **head** tag, but I feel like it's too much to create a seperate javascript file for each view and I won't be able to use **PHP** in them, which I must.

So I am asking you guys, is there a solution to my problem or am I doomed to have my pages clustered with script blocks all around ?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

Could there be a way to put the view specific javascript (of all views) in a single file and somehow seperate it in modules, and only load a specific module for the desired view ?

Let's say **viewsJS.js** holds all the view specific javascript:

```
module ("customerInfo", 
    $(".someClass").html("Bla bla bla");
);

module ("invoiceInfo", 
    // Some code to be executed when the invoiceInfo module is loaded
);
```

Once the javascript for each module (views) is defined, there would be a way to load them into their corresponding view. The thing is, I cannot have a script block in my view to "load" the module, so.. i'm clueless.

Comment: have you tried a module system like commonjs / amd ?

Comment: You don't have to embed PHP in your scripts.  You can instead drop such information into "data-" attributes in HTML elements, or something like that.

Comment: Adding javascript to the bottom of the page and not to the header is bad practice.

Comment: @Derfder: Why would that be?

Comment: Check some tutorials on the internet, where the guys place some javascript stuff at the end and and then are trying to find out 2 minutes what mistake they have made ;)

Comment: Another thing is that some sliders or other things that can flicker etc. when js is loaded as last thing. Btw. Google guys themsleves recommend to put their tracking code (because some problems when loaded as last) from before </body> to right after <body> or in header so I guess it's way safer to load scripts at first and then everything else. Sure yu can add `defer` and stuff to fix that a little bit, but I would go with header instead of footer any day ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create this folder structure in your `application/views`

```
/includes/javascript.php
/template.php
```

then put your main code in **template.php**:

```
<html>
<head>
  <?php echo $this->load->view('includes/javascript'); ?>
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">some header stuff</div>
...
```

And place all your javascript in **javascript.php** in

```
application/views/includes
```

like for example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The finale output would look like in your browser like:

```
<html>
<head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">some header stuff</div>
...
```

For loading specific javascript files you can do something like that in your javascript view:

```
<?php if (is_frontpage()) : ?>
   <script src="http://localhost/javascriptforfrontpage.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (is_contact()) : ?>
   <script src="http://localhost/javscriptforcontactpage.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php // this would be loaded everywhere ?>
<script src="http://localhost/javascripteverypage.js"></script>
```

Loading only customer info javascript:

1st you send from your controller to your view `$data['load_js_customer_info']` e.g. like:

```
public function customerInfo()
    {

        $data['load_js_customer_info'] = "Customer Info";
        $data['customer'] = $this->mdl_admin->get_customer();
        $this->load->view('template', $data);
    }
```

and in view (that contains all javascript) you make a condition:

```
 <?php if ($load_js_customer_info) : ?>
   <script src="http://localhost/javscriptforcustomerinfo.js"></script>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

so, if it's not from customer info controller, the javscript is not loaded.

Comment: Your answer could use some clarifications. I don't really understand what you truely mean by "meta". I suppose your second "meta" is actually "javascript".

Comment: Forget the meta. Anyway, did it work for loading javascript this way?

Comment: I'm not sure how it would solve my problem. The way I interpret your answer is that your includes/javascript view would be a PHP file holding the javascript for ALL views. In that case, I would just include a javascript file holding the code for all views, but that's not what I need. I need to somehow load only the javascript for that specific view (customerInfo) in this case.

Comment: you make a condition. e.g. you send $data['js_customer_info'] and make an if condition. wait a sec I will update my answer

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if it works. This way you can also set the name of your header, title nav item for menus etc. If you wish, you could make it more advanced and grab all the data from db, if you are building some cms system, for example.

Comment: It would work yes, I would implement a more dynamic templating system however, but the main idea is good. I decided put this idea of optimization on hold for the moment, but if I were to implement it I would use something like CommonJS or requireJS and load needed modules dynamically. Thanks for your help though.